# How to save thousand data in Parse Platform NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform

I am new to the parse platform and i'm trying to insert 81000 rows of data in to the Parse DB, here the code

```
        const uri = "/the.json"
        const res = await axios.get(uri)
        const dataresult = Object.keys(res.data)

        if (dataresult.length > 0) {
            res.data.forEach(function (datakp) {
                var kp = new Parse.Object("theClass");
                kp.save(datakp)
                    .then((res) => {
                        console.log('oke ' + res.id)
                    }),
                    (error) => {
                        console.log('err : '+ error.message)
                    }
            })
         }
```

There is no error in console log, and no data is saved in Parse DB, but if I only insert 1000 rows, it will save to the database.

EG:

```
            if (dataresult.length > 0) {
            res.data.forEach(function (datakp, index) {
                if (index < 1000) {
                 var kp = new Parse.Object("theClass");
                 kp.save(datakp)
                    .then((res) => {
                        console.log('oke ' + res.id)
                    }),
                    (error) => {
                        console.log('err : '+ error.message)
                    }
                })
               }
           }
```

Thank You

**UPDATE**

I fix this case based on answer @davi-macêdo
here a complete code

```
    const uri = "/the.json"
    const res = await axios.get(uri)
    const dataresult = Object.keys(res.data)
    const objs = [];
    const theKP = Parse.Object.extend("theClass")
    if (dataresult.length > 0) {
        res.data.forEach(function (datakp) {
            var thekp = new theKP()
            thekp.set(datakp)
            objs.push(thekp);
        })
     }

    Parse.Object.saveAll(objs)
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log('oke updated ' + dataresult.length)
                }),
                (error) => {
                    console.log('err : '+ error.message)
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way is using `Parse.Object.saveAll` function. Something like this:

```js
        const uri = "/the.json"
        const res = await axios.get(uri)
        const dataresult = Object.keys(res.data)
        const objs = [];

        if (dataresult.length > 0) {
            res.data.forEach(function (datakp) {
                objs.push(new Parse.Object("theClass", datakp));
            })
         }

        Parse.Object.saveAll(objs)
                    .then((res) => {
                        console.log('oke ' + res.id)
                    }),
                    (error) => {
                        console.log('err : '+ error.message)
                    }
```

Anyways, since you have no error and no data currently being saved, you might be kitting some memory limit. So that's something you also need to be aware about.

Comment: Hello, your solution with saveAll work and create 81000 object, but no record data, only create ObjectID, ACL, updateAt, and createdAt. But its closed now.. thanks :)

Comment: Thanks you, its work now with using set before push.. :), you save my day..

Comment: Just fixed the code for future reference

Answer (score 0):

You're probably hitting rate limits, I can't imagine saving 81,000 records in one shot is normal behaviour for many applications.

I looked through the documentation and couldn't find anything that might mention a save limit, however sending 1000 requests would trigger most rate limit protection